# My websites are being cached but not checking if they're modified and just using the 'old' cached version

Tags: .htaccess, server

Firstly, I have a main website on my server. Then folders of different sites.

So the file structure is like this:

_Other Website (folder)

_Another Website (folder)

index.html (for main site)

.htaccess

So I have a .htacces in the root of my dir, does the settings for the htaccess apply to all the websites, even those in folders?

Also, my sites do not seem to update without me refreshing a few times. This is the htaccess:

Hi guys,

If I update my site, then go back on it, it takes like 3-5 refreshes before the new content appears.

I thought that I had my htaccess file configured so that the html and css gets cached, and it checks whether it has been modified. If it hasnt been modded, then just load from cache, if it has been modded then redownload it.

This is my htaccess file:

```
# Use PHP5.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php
# enable expirations
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "modification plus 3 weeks"
ExpiresByType image/gif "modification plus 3 week"
ExpiresByType image/png "modification plus 3 week"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "modification plus 3 week"
ExpiresByType image/pjpeg "modification plus 3 week"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "modification plus 3 week"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "modification plus 3 week"
# compress text, HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and XML
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
# remove browser bugs
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent
```

It is caching the HTML and CSS, but it isn't checking to see if the one on the server is newer than the cached, and so it calls up the cached version which is 'old'. Anyone know how to fix this?